# Three.js not rendering on existing canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I created a canvas with an id of 'canvas' which I provided as an argument to the WebGLRenderer of Three.js. However, nothing is showing up on that canvas. If I append the domElement to the document, the canvas shows up on the bottom but I would like to draw on my existing canvas. Is there an extra setting I have to change?

I am using this example code to start off with:

```
  ctx = $('canvas').getContext('2d');
  var canvasElm = $('canvas');
  canvasWidth = parseInt(canvasElm.width);
  canvasHeight = parseInt(canvasElm.height);
  canvasTop = parseInt(canvasElm.style.top);
  canvasLeft = parseInt(canvasElm.style.left);

  var scene = new THREE.Scene(); // Create a Three.js scene object.
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, canvasWidth / canvasHeight, 0.1, 1000); // Define the perspective camera's attributes.

  var renderer = window.WebGLRenderingContext ? new THREE.WebGLRenderer(canvasElm) : new THREE.CanvasRenderer(); // Fallback to canvas renderer, if necessary.
  renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight); // Set the size of the WebGL viewport.
  //document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement); // Append the WebGL viewport to the DOM.

  var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(20, 20, 20); // Create a 20 by 20 by 20 cube.
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000FF }); // Skin the cube with 100% blue.
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material); // Create a mesh based on the specified geometry (cube) and material (blue skin).
  scene.add(cube); // Add the cube at (0, 0, 0).

  camera.position.z = 50; // Move the camera away from the origin, down the positive z-axis.

  var render = function () {
   cube.rotation.x += 0.01; // Rotate the sphere by a small amount about the x- and y-axes.
   cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

   renderer.render(scene, camera); // Each time we change the position of the cube object, we must re-render it.
   requestAnimationFrame(render); // Call the render() function up to 60 times per second (i.e., up to 60 animation frames per second).
  };

  render(); // Start the rendering of the animation frames.
```

I am using Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) if that helps.

Comment: Try `renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: myCanvas } );`

Comment: I tried that the first time. didn't work either.. But I found out that I can make a div and then put the renderer's domElement into the div...

Answer (score 10):

Your jquery selector is wrong (I am assuming it is jquery).
`var canvasElm = $('canvas');` creates a new canvas element.
If you want to select a canvas that has the id of 'canvas', use..
`var canvasElm = $('#canvas');`
But this then gets a jquery object / list, so to get the actual canvas (first item in the list) you could use..
`var canvasElm = $('#canvas')[0];`

eg.

```
var canvasElm = $('#canvas')[0];
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: canvasElm } );
```

You would probably be better just using js without jquery.
eg.

```
canvasElm = document.getElementById('canvas');
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: canvasElm } );
```

Comment: woops, I just saw how old this questions is.

Comment: I wish someone were to answer my old, abandoned, questions. Anyways, +1 cuz you solved my problem right before I was about to ask a question here.